# DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints

Tags: encryption, tls1.2

I have a Java webapp (ignite realtime xmpp server) that uses LDAP to authenticate and authorize users.

Recently the LDAP server upgraded it's cipher suite to more secure ciphers. I was not able to get my app to talk to this LDAP server until I downgraded the minimum keySize allowed in the /jre/lib/security/java.security file, e.g.

```
#jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 2048
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024
```

I added the [JCE 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) to update ciphers in the jre the app uses, new ciphers showed up (I used [this program](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-679609085.html) and compared the before and after)

I enabled the ciphers in the webapp's admin console - specifically:

```
 > *       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

 > *       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
 > *       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

I used [this program](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/tools/SSLTest.java) to see what ciphers the LDAP server was using:

with the following result:

```
Testing server - upgraded endpoint
Given this client's capabilities ([SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]),             the server prefers protocol=TLSv1.2,     cipher=TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Testing server - non-upgraded endpoint
Given this client's capabilities ([SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]),     the server prefers protocol=TLSv1.2, cipher=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

The app could talk to old LDAP (and a non-upgraded endpoint in a cluster) with the following java.security setting:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 2048
```

when the endpoint was upgraded (it was put behind an F5 load balancer), I could not get the app to connect, until downgrading the minimum keySize. The certificate chain for LDAP (new vs. old endpoints) did not change.

```
openssl s_client -connect newLDAP:636
```

shows a 2048 public key, as it does for the oldLDAP, the only difference was the stronger cipher - and maybe TLS version 1 vs 1.2 depending on the openssl version on the machine I tried openssl s_client from.

The xmpp web app :5223 and admin console :9091 of the app also use SSL, and each of these also have 2048 bit public keys.

The error in the app's log files is:

```
"DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints"
```

The constraint mentioned above I believe references the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms java.security file property.

I am confused as to why apparently more secure ciphers now require a smaller minimum keySize for the app and the LDAP connection to work.

I must be missing something or be doing something wrong.

Here are some stack traces from the app's log:

```
    2017.07.25 18:54:32 WARN  [Jetty-QTP-AdminConsole-98]: org.jivesoftware.admin.LoginLimitManager - Failed admin console login attempt by <myuserid> from <myIP>
    2017.07.25 18:54:33 INFO  [Server SR - 881162561]: org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketReadingMode - STARTTLS negotiation (with: org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketConnection@1248cf94 socket: Socket[addr=/78.46.93.108,port=57984,localport=5269] session: org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalIncomingServerSession@2843cab status: 1 address: <xyz>.com/5c3gn5yu6p id: 5c3gn5yu6p) failed.
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1431)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
            at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.TLSStreamHandler.doHandshake(TLSStreamHandler.jav a:241)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.TLSStreamHandler.start(TLSStreamHandler.java:178)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketConnection.startTLS(SocketConnection.java:1 95)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketReadingMode.negotiateTLS(SocketReadingMode. java:87)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.BlockingReadingMode.readStream(BlockingReadingMod e.java:138)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.BlockingReadingMode.run(BlockingReadingMode.java: 76)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketReader.run(SocketReader.java:145)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints
            at sun.security.ssl.DHCrypt.checkConstraints(DHCrypt.java:237)
            at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientKeyExchange(ServerHandshaker.java:1599)
            at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:269)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.TLSStreamHandler.doTasks(TLSStreamHandler.java:34 4)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.TLSStreamHandler.doHandshake(TLSStreamHandler.jav a:254)
            ... 7 more













    2017.07.25 18:54:36 INFO  [Server SR - 1692736043]: org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketReadingMode - STARTTLS negotiation (with: org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketConnection@7b80ac6e socket: Socket[addr=/136.243.42.223,port=47704,localport=5269] session: org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalIncomingServerSession@330ab9e3 status: 1 address: <xyz>.com/5rljrbkums id: 5rljrbkums) failed.
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1431)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
            at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.TLSStreamHandler.doHandshake(TLSStreamHandler.jav a:241)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.TLSStreamHandler.start(TLSStreamHandler.java:178)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketConnection.startTLS(SocketConnection.java:1 95)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketReadingMode.negotiateTLS(SocketReadingMode. java:87)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.BlockingReadingMode.readStream(BlockingReadingMod e.java:138)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.BlockingReadingMode.run(BlockingReadingMode.java: 76)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketReader.run(SocketReader.java:145)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints
            at sun.security.ssl.DHCrypt.checkConstraints(DHCrypt.java:237)
            at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientKeyExchange(ServerHandshaker.java:1599)
            at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:269)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.TLSStreamHandler.doTasks(TLSStreamHandler.java:34 4)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.TLSStreamHandler.doHandshake(TLSStreamHandler.jav a:254)
            ... 7 more





    2017.07.25 19:03:00 ERROR [Jetty-QTP-AdminConsole-56]: org.jivesoftware.openfire.ldap.LdapAuthProvider - Error connecting to LDAP server
    javax.naming.CommunicationException: <myLDAP>:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints]
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:226)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:137)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClientFactory.createPooledConnection(LdapClientFactory.ja va:64)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections.<init>(Connections.java:115)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool.getPooledConnection(Pool.java:132)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapPoolManager.getLdapClient(LdapPoolManager.java:329)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1606)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2746)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
            at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
            at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
            at org.jivesoftware.util.JiveInitialLdapContext.<init>(JiveInitialLdapContext.java :43)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.ldap.LdapManager.getContext(LdapManager.java:568)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.ldap.LdapManager.findUserDN(LdapManager.java:975)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.ldap.LdapManager.findUserDN(LdapManager.java:928)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.ldap.LdapAuthProvider.authenticate(LdapAuthProvider.j ava:126)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.AuthFactory.authenticate(AuthFactory.java:217)
            at org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:175)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.ja va:1669)
            at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:39)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.ja va:1652)
            at org.jivesoftware.util.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:76)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.ja va:1652)
            at org.jivesoftware.util.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingF ilter.java:53)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.ja va:1652)
            at org.jivesoftware.admin.PluginFilter.doFilter(PluginFilter.java:80)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.ja va:1652)
            at org.jivesoftware.admin.AuthCheckFilter.doFilter(AuthCheckFilter.java:162)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.ja va:1652)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:22 3)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:11 27)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185 )
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:106 1)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandler Collection.java:215)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.jav a:110)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635 )
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints
            at sun.security.ssl.DHCrypt.checkConstraints(DHCrypt.java:237)
            at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:712)
            at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:268)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:376)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:203)
            ... 56 more
```

Thanks for any insight, 
sm

Comment: I'm not sure what you're question is. The server is apparently using a 1024-bit DH group, when before it was using 2048 bits. Complain to the server admin.

Comment: How can I verify the server (I assume you mean LDAP) is using a 1024-bit group? I mentioned connecting to the LDAP servers with openssl s_client and the Java SSLTest program. Openssl shows the public key is 2048-bit, the SSLTest program shows the TLS version and cipher.

Comment: "The public key ..." with DHE cipher suites there are two public keys, the long term authentication public key which is usually RSA and the DH public key which changes for every connection. I always use the server tester at ssllabs.com for getting a good profile of server SSL functionality.

Comment: Thanks for that clue. Unfortunately I can't use sslabs.com since the LDAP server is inaccessible outside of our network and both the XMPP and LDAP servers run SSL on ports different than 443. I mentioned the LDAP server went behind a new F5 (VIPRION) load balancer - I wonder if it's the ephemeral key that's causing an issue  similar to this ... https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/dhe-key-exchange-why-is-ephemeral-key-only-1024bit-long - any idea how to test this?

Comment: I tried the openssl command mentioned here - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89773/how-to-check-if-a-server-is-not-vulnerable-to-logjam (openssl s_client -connect myLDAP:636 -cipher "EDH" | grep -i "Server Temp Key"), and didn't see ephemeral key info - I also tried a variation with just grep -i "key" but then only saw the 2048 public key.

Comment: I can't really offer you much help remotely. [Here](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/Assessment-Tools) is a list of tools provided by the guy that created the ssllabs tool. In one comment he said he particularly likes sslyze.

Comment: People who come to this question might be interested in [What does “Reason: DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52419688/562769)

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on my own question, I'm pretty sure I confirmed it is a ephemeral key exchange issue on the new LDAP system as originally suggested by [James K Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/james-k-polk)! His suggestion of [SSLyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze/) was also extremely helpful.

I ran the following commands on the new and old LDAP systems which I think shows the new system only supports up to 1024-bit key exchange, while the old system may not even do key exchange, which may be why the stronger DH keySize setting in the JRE's java.security file worked (e.g. it wasn't being used).

```
python -m sslyze --tlsv1_2 --starttls=auto myLDAP:636



 AVAILABLE PLUGINS
 -----------------

  OpenSslCipherSuitesPlugin
  HeartbleedPlugin
  OpenSslCcsInjectionPlugin
  CertificateInfoPlugin
  SessionResumptionPlugin
  CompressionPlugin
  SessionRenegotiationPlugin
  FallbackScsvPlugin
  HttpHeadersPlugin



 CHECKING HOST(S) AVAILABILITY
 -----------------------------

   myLDAP:636                       => 0.1.2.3




 SCAN RESULTS FOR myLDAP:636 - 0.1.2.3
 -------------------------------------------------

 * TLSV1_2 Cipher Suites:
     Preferred:
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384               DH-1024 bits   256 bits
     Accepted:
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384             ECDH-384 bits  256 bits
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384             ECDH-384 bits  256 bits
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                ECDH-384 bits  256 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256               DH-1024 bits   256 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                  DH-1024 bits   256 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384               DH-1024 bits   256 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384                   -              256 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                      -              256 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256                   -              256 bits
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256             ECDH-384 bits  128 bits
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256             ECDH-384 bits  128 bits
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                ECDH-384 bits  128 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256               DH-1024 bits   128 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                  DH-1024 bits   128 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256               DH-1024 bits   128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256                   -              128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256                   -              128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                      -              128 bits
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA               ECDH-384 bits  112 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                 DH-1024 bits   112 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                     -              112 bits
     Rejected:
    <snipped>


 SCAN COMPLETED IN 0.16 S
 ------------------------











python -m sslyze --tlsv1_2 --starttls=auto oldLDAP:636



 AVAILABLE PLUGINS
 -----------------

  CompressionPlugin
  OpenSslCipherSuitesPlugin
  CertificateInfoPlugin
  FallbackScsvPlugin
  OpenSslCcsInjectionPlugin
  SessionResumptionPlugin
  SessionRenegotiationPlugin
  HttpHeadersPlugin
  HeartbleedPlugin



 CHECKING HOST(S) AVAILABILITY
 -----------------------------

   oldLDAP:636                       => 4.5.6.7




 SCAN RESULTS FOR oldLDAP:636 - 4.5.6.7
 -------------------------------------------------------------

 * TLSV1_2 Cipher Suites:
     Preferred:
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA                          -              128 bits
     Accepted:
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                ECDH-256 bits  256 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                      -              256 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256                   -              256 bits
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                ECDH-256 bits  128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256                   -              128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                      -              128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA                          -              128 bits
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA               ECDH-256 bits  112 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                     -              112 bits
     Rejected:
    <snipped>


 SCAN COMPLETED IN 0.34 S
 ------------------------
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to edit your question to provide more information. Answers are for answers.

Comment: @transilvlad, this seems like an answer. The other post, on the other hand, should have been an edit to the post.