# What does "Reason: DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints" mean?

Tags: java, security, encryption

I saw this error when I wanted to connect to another machine:

> SEVERE: Could not create connection
>   XXXXX: XXXXX Error establishing socket to host and port: XXXXX:XXXXX. Reason: DHPublicKey does not comply to algorithm constraints

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason was that the server only supported weak ciphers. While updating the server is certainly the clean/good solution, the quick one is to remove the constraints as mentioned [here](https://wuliangx.wordpress.com/2018/05/19/cannot-connect-to-database-through-jdbc/):

Within `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/security/java.security` or - depending on your OS - `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config` you have a line

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
```

Notice the `DH keySize < 1024`. So no keys which are smaller are allowed.

Replacing this with

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, \
```

or completely removing the `DH keySize < 1024` part could solve the problem.

You can do this via

```
$ sed -i "s/ DH keySize < 1024,//" /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/security/java.security
```

Comment: Using Centos 8, Java 8, tomcat 9, I had to make that change in /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config

Comment: Does this make any impact on overall security ?

Comment: @Hiren the disabled algorithms are disabled because they are considered "not safe enough". Obviously, allowing the use of those older algorithms/configuration parameters will be less safe than using the newer ones, but how significant that risk is would depend a lot of your situation (it is not the same sharing banking data over the internet than profile pictures in your internal network).